# How do cursors work on Firestore's REST API?

Tags: firebase, rest, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to build a structured query using the rest API for Firestore.
There is one thing I don't quite understand. According to the docs I need to provide a cursor for the `startAt` or `endAt` arguments(when used), and a cursor consists of two props, the first one is an array of `Values`.

```
{
  "values": [
    {
      object(Value)
    }
  ],
  "before": boolean
}
```

The docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1beta1/StructuredQuery#cursor.

My question is, how exactly am I supposed to use this?
It is my understanding that a cursor represents a position on a list of documents(in this case, a list made by a query), but how do the values prop comes into play?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cursor represents a document in query results, not a **position** in the list (since the position may change between calls).

The values you specify in the REST API call are the values from the anchor document that you want to start at. At a minimum you need to specify the values that you use in the query, so if you order by a field `index` and filtering by a field `category`, you will need to specify the values of those fields from the anchor document.

Comment: Just to verify that I got it correctly. when using a cursor I need to provide the properties and values for and then specific document and behind the scenes, a document with those exact properties and values will be searched and used as the anchor. So technically if I have multiple documents with the same exact props and values, there is no guarantee that the anchor will point to the same document each time?

Comment: Yup, that's pretty much it. Firestore finds the index based on your query, then finds the anchor document based on the values you supply, and then starts returning results from there. If documents can have the same values you'll have to include the document ID, which is used as a tie breaker in that case. This might actually always be needed. I'm not sure because I have only done this with the SDKs, where I pass in an actual (complete) document instance with all values *and* the ID.